# Having issue with understanding two singleton Php code for conecting to mongoDb

Tags: php, oop, mongodb

I have these two code to use to connect to mongodb.

First i used this code but this doesn't seem to work.I dont know why.

```
class DbConnection
{
    static $db = NULL;

    static function getMongoCon()
    {
        if (self::$db === null)
        {
            try {
                $m = new Mongo("mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017");


            } catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
                die('Failed to connect to MongoDB '.$e->getMessage());
            }
            self::$db = $m;
        }
        else
        {
            return self::$db;
        }
    }
}
```

After this i used this way to connect mongo in another class

```
   $db=DbConnection::getMongoCon();
   $database=$db->databasename;
     $collection=$db->users;
```

But this doesn't seem to work always . i always get error $db not defined or some other undefined error.

Second Code is this . which i used to connect to mongodb without having to create multiple connection. This works fine without having problem.

```
class DbConnection{

    static protected $_instance;

    protected $db = null;

    final protected function __construct() {
        $m = new Mongo("mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017");
        $this->db = $m->selectDB( "databasename" );
    }

    static public function getInstance() {
        if (!(self::$_instance instanceof self)) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->db;
    }

    final protected function __clone() { }
}
```

To use this code in another class i used

```
  $db=DbConnection::getInstance()->getConnection();

         $collection=$db->users;
```

I dont know why second one worked but not the first code. if i use both in mysql both works fine.
Also can this be issue than in second code i have create connection to mongodatabase and kept it open and directly used in another class.

please describe simply why the second code worked fine and first didn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first piece of code, when the `$db` variable is `null` and you create a new connection, your `getMongoCon` function **doesn't return anything**, hence when you try to use it on the example, `$db=DbConnection::getMongoCon();` end ups asigning `null` to the `$db` variable.

To make it work correctly, you should do something like this:

```
...
static function getMongoCon()
{
    if (self::$db === null)
    {
        try {
            $m = new Mongo("mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017");

        } catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
            die('Failed to connect to MongoDB '.$e->getMessage());
        }
        self::$db = $m;
    }

    return self::$db;
}
...
```